# Repeatedly background task ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using `ionic-framework` / `cordova` for building my app.
I've installed this plugin [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) for working in background mode.

**Q:** But now how can I do a task that repeats every 30 minutes in background?

Do you know another plugin that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

According to the repository that you used the code must look like this:

```js
// Run when the device is ready
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

    // Android customization
    // To indicate that the app is executing tasks in background and being paused would disrupt the user.
    // The plug-in has to create a notification while in background - like a download progress bar.
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ 
        title:  'TheTitleOfYourProcess',
        text:   'Executing background tasks.'
    });

    // Enable background mode
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

    // Called when background mode has been activated
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

        // Set an interval of 30 minutes (1800000 milliseconds)
        setInterval(function () {

            // The code that you want to run repeatedly

        }, 1800000);
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$timeout` and `$interval` for this task with centain period of time

[Angular doc for interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: All Angular code is suspended when an ionic/cordova app is in the background on the device. While `$timeout` and `$interval` are the correct answer for when the app is in the foreground, it doesn't help when running on the device.